# Is "Hoch steigen die Drachen" ambiguous?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching a German nursery rhyme (listening practice) and there was the line: *Hoch steigen die Drachen, das freut jedes Kind.* I was a bit alarmed because I thought they were talking about dragons, not, as it turned out, about kites. Was there something about the phrasing that could have ruled out dragons, or is it just context? The nominative plurals of *Drache* (dragon) and *Drachen* (kite) are the same.

Comment: Well of course dragons mountaineering would be possible and probably may be of enjoyment value for kids. But kites raising is just much more likely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Morphologically, it is ambiguous. Semantically, it is not really, since *Drachen steigen* is a phrase that typically refers to kites. Using it with dragons would be a mismatch.

This mismatch could be utilized intentionally, in order to transport some meaning. So, the meaning "dragons" is not ruled out on strictly grammatical terms.  But in *locutio propria* ("literal speech", i.e. when speaking unironically, non-metaphorically), one would not do this.

---

Just as a side note, *den Drachen steigen lassen*, or *seinen Drachen steigen lassen* also has the meaning of "getting sexually aroused", or even "getting an erection". This is metaphor is probably most prominently popularized by the song *Geh zu ihr* from the band *Puhdys*, part of the sound track of the film classic *Paul und Paula*, from 1973, with the chorus having the lyrics:

> Geh zu ihr, und lass deinen Drachen steigen

Another instance in popular culture of that not-so-subtle sexual metaphor is the song *Ist das alles?* from *Die Ärzte* from 1986, with the lines:

> Dann bekam ich eine Freundin und ich gab mich seriös
> Doch etwas unter ihrer Bluse machte mich nervös
> Ich wollte, doch ich hatte keine Ahnung
> Und kein Vertrauen in mein Glück
> Da ließ sie meinen Drachen steigen
> Jetzt gab es kein Zurück

As usual with bawdy metaphors, the sexual subtext is ambiguous in both cases.

Comment: So are you saying that you'd never use *steigen* with a dragon? What would you use instead? Would *aufsteigen* or *erheben* work?

Comment: They could in principle, too. Anything flying which ascends can be referred to "XXX steigt (hoch)". But from context it's quite unambiguous.

Comment: @RDBury I tried to go more into detail and updated my answer. Not sure if I get the point across, please let me know.

Comment: @planetmaker - It depends on the context; maybe they're colorful balloon dragons in a parade. But in this case they were showing a drawing of a kid flying a kite so the context was pretty clear. According to DWDS *Drachen* is a more common word, but for some reason *Drache* was in my active vocabulary while *Drachen* wasn't. Perhaps dragons are more common than kites in the TV I watch.

Comment: I think I take your meaning, though my knowledge of Latin is even more sketchy than my knowledge of German. DWDS shows *Drachen* + *steigen* as a colocation, at least with *Drachen* as object. A "kite" in English is also a type of bird. (I'm not sure if there's an exact German translation; Wiktionary says *Milan* but I think that's just an approximation.) Theoretically you could train it to fly on command like a hawk. But if you said someone is "flying a kite" it would be  pretty clear that you meant the kind made of paper and wood.

Comment: @RDBury I added a short explanation for the latin phrase. I apologize. It is a term I could explain in German, but it is hard for me to explain it in English. In German, we differentiate between "eigentlicher Rede" (locutia propia, literally "proper speech") and "uneigentlicher Rede" (locutia impropia, literally "improper speech", but that is a mis-translation of the term). Locutia impropia is anytime when the words you say differ from the intended meaning, for instance in irony or metaphor.

Comment: @RDBury Indeed, in singular one can make actually a distinction, while in plural not: Der Drache --> the dragon, the mythological fire-spitting winged creature. Der Drachen --> The kite, the thing children fly in autumn on the harvested fields. Plural in both cases is "die Drachen". I'd not bet much on every native speaker getting this always right (actually not even on me).